# CodeIgniter on subdomain and htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm trying to setup a website based on CodeIgniter.
For developing I want to have the `domain dev.XXX.com`

I changed my structure so I've got a `no_www` and a `public_www` folder.
Both are in the root of `dev.XXX.com`

So my idea was to rewrite url's form

`dev.XXX.com/index.php/test`

to

`dev.XXX.com/public_www/index.php/test`

So I just want add `public_www` to all the requests

In my htaccess file I've got:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public_www/$1 [L]
```

But I always get 500 - Internal Server Error

Comment: So you want to keep your index.php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory <strike>(`public_www`)</strike> of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#if its on dev.xxx.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.XXX\.com$ [NC] 
#if its not already public_www/ rewrite to public_www/
RewriteRule ^(?!public_www/)(.*)$ /public_www/$1 [L,NC]
```

The rule you had would lead to an infinite rewrite and subsequent 500 error. The one above should prevent that.

**EDIT**

> could you maybe explain why my version leads into a infinite loop

I am likely incorrect about the infinite loop, but below is what will happen

1. Start with any input
2. `^(.*)$` pattern will match any input
3. It will rewrite to `/public_www/$1`
4. .htaccess rules will be run again
5. `^(.*)$` pattern will match rewritten input `/public_www/$1`
6. It will rewrite to `/public_www/public_www/$1`
7. At this point it will likely fail as the directory does not exist...

Your RewriteRule pattern `^(.*)$` will match all input and will rewrite to . The .htaccess rules will then be run again

Comment: could you maybe explain why my version leads into a infinite loop?

Comment: right now my .htaccess file is in my document root /
under the root I've got the no_www and the public_www folder
when I replace my htaccess with yours nothing happens
when I create a new .htaccess in my public_www folder as you said I still get Error 500 when accessing the public_www folder

Comment: @skelle the .htaccess should be in the `DocumentRoot`. Can you give me full URL that you tested with

Comment: doesn't the L mean LAST? so I thought he stops after this rule
I will post an public URL in some minutes

Comment: @skelle `L` does mean last and will stop processing rules further down, but there are cases e.g. when you rewrite to a directory that the rules need to be run again, from the start, see #1 in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules

Comment: Ulrich, +1 on the explanation -- except that it will be an unbounded iteration failing on Max redirects.  My only quibble is that IIRC if you look at the rewrite.log for this type of replacement, it is usually safer to drop the leading / on relative targets in Per Dir processing (e.g. `.htaccess` files) -- less potential bizarre side-effects.

Comment: did it again from scratch... fine working now :) thanks!
can you also tell me how to change the file that requests to dev.xxx.com/index.php will be rewritten to dev.xxx.com/public_www/index.php (should happen with all files)

Comment: @skelle I don't understand what you are asking - can you give me more detail e.g. do you mean this does not work for index.php?

Comment: it is working fine with the index.php
but when I've got links to dev.xxx.com/index.php/foo
ALL stuff like this should be rewritten to dev.xxx.com/public_www/index.php
but I want to hide the public_www from the user in the url bar